# When do an empty search return to home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys i have this problem with my search bar - when i don't enter any keywords it still shows results. How do i tell it if there are no keywords in the search bar (even if there are just spaces in the search bar) just to redirect it to the same page until there is actually something to search for ?

here is my code:

```
-if !@movies.empty?
  .row
    .large-12.columns
      h3="Results for '#{params[:query]}'"
      table.movie_table
        -@movies.each do |movie|
          tr
            td =link_to movie.title, movie_path(movie)
            td =image_tag(movie.image_url)
-else
  .row
    .large-12.columns
  h3="No results found for '#{params[:query]}'"
```

Comment: I assume `@movies` is an array of Movie model objects?  Or is it something else?   Are you saying that you never see the message "No results found for ..."  Is it possible that `@movies` has a count > 0?

Comment: No i am saying that if i just click into the search tab and press enter i still see movie results for '' (basically no key words). I am looking for a method to say if the search bar is empty or it just has spaces in it (either way) to just redirect me to the initial home page root_path if you wish.

Comment: Basically my question is how do i say if the query is empty (that includes even if it has a thousand spaces in it and no actual keywords) redirect_to root_path ?

Comment: Ok, you're testing `@movies` in your view.  That is presumably a collection of found objects.   But your `<h3>` legend relies on `params[:query]` to display what was asked for.   (Normally, I'd probably assign `params[:query]` to a variable in the controller or pass as local because you try to do as little in views as possible.)  In any case, `redirect_to root_path if params[:query].blank?` in your controller should do what I think you have in mind.

Comment: You were right. That works. If you could write your answer so i can close this question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're testing `@movies` in your view.  That presumably is a collection of found objects.

Your `<h3>` legend on the other hand relies on `params[:query]` to display what was asked for. (Often one would assign `params[:query]` to a variable in the controller or -- even better, pass it as local -- because you try to do as little in views as possible.)  It seems you'd prefer to test `params[:query]` since that would be the text that the user submitted to query against.

Using `redirect_to root_path if params[:query].blank?` (or any other `_path` or `_url`) in your controller instead of letting it render the view when the query is whitespace will do what I think you want.

Comment: You bet, glad it helped.